# Ask user to select desired data range from EXCEL using MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, input, plot

In order to plot data from Excel in the same Excel file using Matlab, is it possible to ask for the user to select the desired range instead of defining the range in the Matlab code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) offers the option of loading data interactively, though it's Windows only.

```
out = xlsread(fileName,-1);
```